# F_SETPIPE_SZ undeclared

Tags: c, linux, fcntl

I have included following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

I have also tried to use

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before `#include <unistd.h>`, but it also does not help.

I try to use `fcntl` and pass it `F_SETPIPE_SZ` as second argument, but I keep getting this error message:

> error: ‘F_SETPIPE_SZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)

I actually found out that I don't need this, but I'm just curious why I can't use it.

Thank you.

So here's solution, thanks to Chrono Kitsune:
Put

```
 #define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before any includes.

Comment: How are you calling `fcntl`.  Can you post that in your question?

Comment: You should `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including any headers. I doubt that will help, but it is worth saying. What does `uname -r` show? If it is less than 2.6.35, you shouldn't have `F_SETPIPE_SZ`. The man page I have documents it as being available since Linux 2.6.35.

Comment: Thanks, it actually did solve problem, I don't know how but it did. And one more problem to. Awesome! Thank you. (And no, my kernel is not that old :) )

Comment: @ChronoKitsune don't define like this. the formal way to enable it is by cli: gcc --std=gnu blabla.

Comment: You shouldn't add the answer to question. Instead post it as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions, and you'll be to accept in a day or two.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr You're correct, but since `_GNU_SOURCE` is a Linux glibc feature test macro ([`man feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)), just like `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, it is perfectly reasonable to simply define the macro on a per-file basis **before including any headers**. The man page specifically states that it is allowed. The important point is to define it before any headers are included, meaning either on the command line or in a file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So here's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411892/f-setpipe-sz-undeclared#comment39643122_25411892), thanks to [Chrono Kitsune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539810/chrono-kitsune):

Put

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before any includes.

You should also pay attention to Chrono Kitsune's other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411892/f-setpipe-sz-undeclared#comment39682023_25411892).

Answer (score 2):

F_SETPIPE_SZ/F_GETPIPE_SZ are relatively recent.  Older kernels (e.g. 2.6.32 as used in RHEL6) don't have them.  If you look in /usr/include/linux/fcntl.h and these constants aren't defined, then this API isn't going to work and you'll have to find some way to bypass it in whatever you're building.